# Como correlacionar arquivos de dois arquivos txt em Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber uma forma de correlacionar palavras iguais em arquivos txt diferentes.
Ele vai ler as palavras de um arquivo txt e procurar essas palavras no outro arquivo txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para veres os elementos em comum entre dois arquivos (listas de palavras) faz a interseção entre os seus sets:

```
with open('arquivo1.txt') as f1, open('arquivo2.txt') as f2:
    content1 = f1.read().split() # dividir por palavras
    content2 = f2.read().split() # dividir por palavras
comuns = set(content1) & set(content2) # {paravras, comuns, nos, dois, arquivos}
```

[Sets em python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MPsL/2)

Comment: mano to criando um lista de objetos aqui... mas na hora que imprimo esta lista de objetos esta dando um saida estranha...  tu manja fazer isso?  `lista_Objetos = []


def cria_lista_objetos(word,indiceArq,qtd):
    lista_ObjetosFun = []
    nomeWord = PalavraIndices(word)
    nomeWord.add_item(indiceArq,qtd)
    lista_ObjetosFun.append(nomeWord)
    return lista_ObjetosFun

for i in palavras_A:
    lista_Objetos = cria_lista_objetos(i,'arquivo1',1)`  e esta dando essa saída:  `[<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x02B39D50>]`

Comment: vou colocar como pergunta entao... aqui no comentario fica dificil mesmo entender..

Comment: Pensei que quando printase a lista de Objetos ia mostrar o nome de cada objeto instanciado dentro da lista... para depois eu escrever em um arquivo.. cada objeto desse, percorrendo a lista

Comment: @WilliamHenrique mas tens só mesmo um objeto na lista. Quando `lista_Objetos = cria_lista_objetos(i,'arquivo1',1)`, simplesmente estás a substituir o valor. Deves querer `lista_Objetos.append(...)`

Comment: subi uma pergunta la.. porque tentei entender aqui e nao consegui... da uma olhada la..  titulo da pergunta é: Lista de objetos em Python

Answer (score 0):

Bom... eu faria desta forma:

Primeiramente guardaria o conteúdo de cada arquivo em uma lista, utilizando
`lista = file.read()`, depois faria um `newlista = lista.split()` o que pegaria cada palavra e colocaria em uma posição da lista, o que resultaria em algo assim:

```
conjunto_A = ['oi','tchaum','ontem','amanha']
conjunto_B = ['oi','tchaum','ontem','amanha','tarde','noite']

palavras_C = [item for item in conjunto_A if item  in conjunto_B]
print(palavras_C)
```

tendo as listas de palavras é só verificar quais palavras da lista A também pertencem do conjunto de palavras da lista B

neste exemplo que dei, a saída é:

```
['oi', 'tchaum', 'ontem', 'amanha']
```

somente os elementos que as duas listas possuem.